# There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My gradle file has an error. The app compiles properly but it generates a runtime exception and crashes instantly. It shows:

`All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)`

Inspection info:

> There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

I'm trying to read data from Firebase Realtime Database and load it into a recyclerview with cardview.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pirewall"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner      "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gradle file add the following dependency:

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
```

So it can be compatible with other android support libraries.

Answer (score 1):

First off, make sure that you're using the latest version of Firebase libraries.

Assuming you are, the solution is to explicitly add the latest version of dependencies for those libraries that are stated to have mixed versions.

If you follow the hint that Android Studio displays:

`Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0`

You will need to add

`implementation “com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0”`(higher version of the two conflicting versions) to your `build.gradle`.

After that, syncing should rebuild the dependencies and resolve the error. If you see a similar error again for a different library, continue to do the same till all such errors are gone.

An easier way to add those dependencies without having to type it out would be to use Android Studio keyboard shortcuts.
 Highlight the error and press “ALT+ENTER”, you’ll see an option to:
`Add Library dependency > Edit Intention settings`

This should open up a menu showing you the problematic dependency. Add that dependency with the version `28.0.0`. Sync and you should see the errors resolved.